# When to call schedule()?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing a driver for device that has no DMA.

Driver start device operation and then waits for operation to complete by pulling *busy* flag from device periodically.

The operation takes 4.5 or 9 microseconds to complete. Under no circumstances device completes operation earlier. No errors will arise from reading state of device later than designated amount of time (9 microseconds).

**Busywait**

All kernel articles found in Internet tell to busywait for intervals this small. They argue that any sleep operation will waste more resources than busywait. Personally, I don't like wasting cycles on trivial wait.

**Schedule/sleep**

I've found out that on target hardware with a process using whole CPU `schedule()` call causing other threads (on empty processor there are no other threads)  can be invoked up to 4 times before device operation completes. When I add more dummy processes to load the CPU, I see that schedule call in my driver gives fairer CPU allocation for concurrently running processes.

Should I call `schedule()` or even `usleep_range()` while waiting for my device, or should I rely on kernel preemption to deal with busywaits?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt), `usleep_range` is what you want for recent kernels.

[Update:  Whoops!  I should have read more carefully.  For < 10us, it says to use `udelay`.  So I guess it depends on how long you are willing to sleep for.]

Comment: OK I should have read it more carefully :-).  I will update my answer.